# How to block TCDL embedded Tag in custom generated Xml

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, templating, configuration

I am generating custom XML from components using a C# TBB, and on migrating from 5.3 to 2011, I can see the following additional markup in my XML.

```
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:10-111" templateURI="tcm:10-1112-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL">
```

Actually there are some embedded components, what our code do, it execute tridionEngine.RenderComponentPresentation and append the xml. so this node getting added part of final XML. this particular ComponentPresentation node was not there in 5.3.

Is there any option setting which I can set to avoid above tags from appearing?

Comment: @NunoLinhares I just wanted to know the group that, what was there in 5.3.   and what is my issue in 2011. and its for my client, i don't have control when they want update. i am not blaming SDL for that

Comment: I know - sorry, long week. It just sounded negative to me (and it's the 2nd time I see you write a similar comment). I'll remove my comment, it is an unfair one too

Answer (score 6):

Are you seeing this in the final published XML? TCDL should get removed by the deployer and cleanup templates if your system is configured properly.

You probably just need the Default Finish Actions in your Page Template. RenderComponentPresentation places the TCDL you are seeing in the output in order to be able to apply SiteEdit/XPM tags. It is safe to remove it using the CleanUp Template if you are not using SiteEdit/XPM (or after any SE/XPM templates if you are using them).

Comment: Hey Chris, i have updated the question, thx

Comment: @Techmaster: Have you used Default Finish Action TBB?

Comment: @Chris, its Page Template, its has set of c# tbbs which generates the XML, there is no default tbb and finish action in this template. its old code which we are migrating to 2011.

Comment: @TechMaster: Read my answer above: To remove the above tags from your final output use the Cleanup Template TBB in your set of c# tbbs at the end. Read my Answer above for details.

Answer (score 4):

Use **Default Finish Action** TBB or in specific **Cleanup Template** TBB along with your C# TBB to remove these tags.

These TBBs are available as Default Template in SDL Tridion 20xx.